# Jquery is not working with html which

Tags: jquery, insert, appendto

First, i have this code

```
<ul id="unselected_list">
   <li class="clearfix" id="p1">
        <img src="img/pic1.jpg" alt="pic1">
        <p>name1</p>
    </li>
     <li class="clearfix" id="p2">
        <img src="img/pic2.jpg" alt="pic2">
        <p>name2</p>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul id="selected_list"></ul>
```

I use jquery appendTo() method to insert `<li>` tag into inside `<ul id="selected_list"></ul>` with this code. It worked.

```
$('#unselected_list li').click(function(){
    $(this).appendTo('#selected_list');
});
   <ul id="unselected_list">
         <li class="clearfix" id="p2">
            <img src="img/pic2.jpg" alt="pic2">
            <p>name2</p>
        </li>
    </ul>

   <ul id="selected_list">
       <li class="clearfix" id="p1">
            <img src="img/pic1.jpg" alt="pic1">
            <p>name1</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

But when i want to click `<li id="p1">` for it to return `<ul id="unselected_list">`, i used this code. It wasn't working.

```
$('#selected_list li').click(function(){
        $(this).appendTo('#unselected_list');
    });
```

Demo Image http://tapchidesign.hostoi.com/help.jpg

How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

When you are attaching the handler `#selected_list` has no descendant `li` element, you should delegate the event, from one of static parents of the element or document object.

```
$('#selected_list').on('click', 'li', function(){
    $(this).appendTo('#unselected_list');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#selected_list li')` returns all of the elements matching that selector at the time your call it. The click event isn't going to bind to elements created after you called the selector.

Bind the click event so that it takes dynamically generated elements into account:

```
$('#selected_list').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $(this).appendTo('#unselected_list');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you-

```
$('#selected_list li[id^="p"]').click(function(){
    $(this).appendTo('#unselected_list');
});
```